# Hide the custom button based on permission set using visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need to hide the custom button which I created in visualforce page.

For one permission set I need to hide this custom button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a [Custom Permission](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_perms_overview.htm&type=5), assign it to the Permission Set, then you can detect its presence:

```
<apex:... rendered="{!not($Permission.HideSpecialButton)}"
```

Note that "negative" permissions are generally not encouraged; you should instead have a custom permission that *shows* the button when present, and assign it to all profiles/permission sets that should have it.

Comment: But my Buttons are created in Visualforce commandbutton coding , so how can i create the custom permission set based on these.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking? I've already answered your question as I understand it. If I'm unclear, please provide additional information.

Comment: @Anish you can add the `rendered` attribute to just about any visualforce tag.  So if the button you want to hide is `<apex:commandButton value="My Button" action="{!doMyButton}" />` you just add the `rendered` attribute (from @sfdcfox's answer), like so:  `<apex:commandButton value="My Button" action="{!doMyButton}" rendered="{!not($Permission.HideSpecialButton)}" />`

Comment: I got your point about rendered attribute but where i need to specify permission set for which i need to hide those button. How i can specify this in custom permission. Do i need to create any validation rule with custom permission.

Comment: @Anish you add custom permissions to a permission set.